# What is the windows command line command for opening a program after a certain amount of time?

Tags: command-line

Say I want to open google in chrome, I know that I can use start chrome "www.google.com", however, what if i want there to be a timer and this page to open after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `TIMEOUT` https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html.

For example: `timeout 1 & start chrome "google.com"`